# C++ output printed twice and error exit code: -1

Tags: c++

I am learning and practicing with C++. I an error when I tried to run the program. I tried different things like changing the sign (<=,>=,<,>) but I don't think they are the problem. I was planning to create different classes for each range of bonus salary but I don't think it is needed to add different classes. I tried to combine 'bonus' and 'total' in one line of code but I need 'bonus' information to be displayed. The instructions are if your old salary is up to $14,999.99 raise 5%, $15,000.00 to $49,999.99 raise 7%, $50,000.00 to $99,999.99 raise 10% and $100,000.00 and higher raise 15%

```
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process terminated with exit code: -1.
```

This is the code

```
// Salary Calculator Program
```

// Intro C++, Lesson 6
// Written by Phong Dau, Jun 2022

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main( )
{
    //Declare variables
  double oldSalary = 0.00;
  double bonus = 0.00;
  double total = 0.00;
    
    //Prompt the user for inputs
  cout << "Enter your old salary: ";
  cin >> oldSalary;

    //Decide salary bonus
  if (oldSalary < 15000.00)
    {
      bonus = oldSalary * 0.05;
      total = bonus + oldSalary;
      cout <<"You will receive a raise of $" <<bonus<<", for a new yearly salary of $"<<total<<endl;
    }
  else if (oldSalary >= 15000.00 < 50000.00)
    {
      bonus = oldSalary * 0.7;
      total = bonus + oldSalary;
      cout <<"You will receive a raise of $" <<bonus<<", for a new yearly salary of $"<<total<<endl;
    }
  else if (oldSalary >= 50000.00 < 100000.00)
    {
      bonus = oldSalary * 0.1;
      total = bonus + oldSalary;
      cout <<"You will receive a raise of $" <<bonus<<", for a new yearly salary of $"<<total<<endl;
    }
  else 
    {
      bonus = oldSalary * 0.15;
      total = bonus + oldSalary;
      cout <<"You will receive a raise of $" <<bonus<<", for a new yearly salary of $"<<total<<endl;
    }
  //end if
  
  system("pause");
  return 0;
} //end of main
```

When I enter few numbers to test the program, the output printed twice except for over $100,000.00. I only want it to be printed once.

```
Enter your old salary:10000
You will receive a raise of $500,for a new yearly salary of $10500
You will receive a raise of $500,for a new yearly salary of $10500
Press any key to continue . . . 

Enter your old salary:20000
You will receive a raise of $1400,for a new yearly salary of $21400
You will receive a raise of $1400,for a new yearly salary of $21400
Press any key to continue . . . 

Enter your old salary:80000
You will receive a raise of $8000,for a new yearly salary of $88000
You will receive a raise of $8000,for a new yearly salary of $88000
Press any key to continue . . . 

Enter your old salary:150000
You will receive a raise of $22500,for a new yearly salary of $172500
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Looks like that last else is missing brackets (which means only bonus = oldSalaray * 0.05; is in the if)

Comment: The first if statement: `if (oldSalary > 14999.99)` -- if this is false, then the only logical possibility is that `oldSalary` is less than or equal to 14999.99. Ok,in that case we proceed to `else if (oldSalary > 49999.99)` -- can you explain exactly when do you expect this `if` statement to ever be true, if you know that oldSalary will always be less than this, at this point? Does this make sense to you? Have you tried [explaining this logic to your rubber duck](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)?

Comment: So the only remaining question is why your program exits with a code of -1.  There's only a single return and it returns 0.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik the if state is true in the last else statement. else 
    bonus = oldSalary * 0.05;
    total = bonus + oldSalary;
    cout <<"You will receive a raise of $" <<bonus<<", for a new yearly salary of $"<<total<<endl;

Comment: @MarkRansom I tried running the code on VSCode and replit but both have the same error.

Comment: Sorry, what's the "same error"? Are you still talking about how it outputs twice? If so, then you haven't read the comments.

Comment: @paddy error exit code of -1 and also printed twice. I added brackets and changed the range of the numbers but still printed twice. I read the comment and still don't understand what I do wrong.

Comment: I edited the code, please take a look. Thank you!!

Comment: ld returned -1 leads me to think your build process failed, if thats the case your code modifications dont get reflected in the final executable. so adding brackets "didnt fix it" becuase youre possibly running the old executable still

Comment: Having such similar outputs makes it difficult to use them to make sure your program is performing as expected. I suggest (for debugging) changing the first `cout <<"You will receive a raise of $" <<bonus<<", for a new yearly salary of $"<<total<<endl;` to `cout << "This is the first block.  oldSalary is " << oldSalary << '\n';`, the second to `cout << "This is the second block.  oldSalary is " << oldSalary << '\n';`, the third to `cout << "This is the third block.  oldSalary is " << oldSalary << '\n';`, the fourth to `cout << "This is the fourth block.  oldSalary is " << oldSalary << '\n';`.

Comment: `if (oldSalary >= 15000.00 < 50000.00)` -- this  does not do what you think it does. If you don't know how to do something in C++, guessing the correct syntax rarely works, even if it is valid grammar. This condition will always be true, now matter what the value of `oldSalary` is. How are you "learning and practicing with C++", which C++ textbook are you using, which chapter are you currently reading, and what material have you covered already?

Comment: On an unrelated topic: note that the only difference between the branches is the raise rate. Applying the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle, the common code should be refactored (to a function in general or, in this case, to after the branches) so it appears only once. You're right that different classes for each rate would not be appropriate, as the OO model doesn't apply to how the rates are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As identified already in the comments, you have a few issues. I'm going to spell them out for you as an answer.

The first issue is that your final `else` is only controlling a single line because it does not enclose the multiple statements in brackets.

```
else 
    bonus = oldSalary * 0.05;
    total = bonus + oldSalary;
    cout <<"You will receive a raise of $" <<bonus<<", for a new yearly salary of $"<<total<<endl;
```

The above is equivalent to:

```
else {
    bonus = oldSalary * 0.05;
}
  
total = bonus + oldSalary;
cout <<"You will receive a raise of $" <<bonus<<", for a new yearly salary of $"<<total<<endl;
```

To fix that, put those statements in a block:

```
else {
    bonus = oldSalary * 0.05;
    total = bonus + oldSalary;
    cout <<"You will receive a raise of $" <<bonus<<", for a new yearly salary of $"<<total<<endl;
}
```

The second issue is multiple issus actually. To start, this kind of thing is totally bogus:

```
if (oldSalary >= 15000.00 < 50000.00)
```

This does not do what you think. You probably wanted:

```
if (oldSalary >= 15000.00 && oldSalary < 50000.00)
```

But that's still incorrect because it's never reached due to your logic being backwards:

```
if (oldSalary > 14999.99) {
   // All salaries above 14999.99
}
else if (oldSalary > 49999.99) {
   // Not reachable     
}
else if (oldSalary > 99999.99) {
   // Not reachable     
}
else
{
   // All salaries less than or equal to 14999.99
}
```

One approach is to reverse the tests such that the things being tested by the "else" are logical possibilities.

```
if (oldSalary > 99999.99) {
   // (99999.99, +inf) -> 15%
}
else if (oldSalary > 49999.99) {
   // (49999.99, 99999.99] -> 10%
}
else if (oldSalary > 14999.99) {
   // (14999.99, 49999.99] -> 7%
}
else
{
   // (-inf, 14999.99] -> 5%
}
```

Also, in this instance you have a very minor boundary issue. You say that it's 5% for anything below 15000.00. However, 14999.99999 is below that but you wrongly assume 14999.99 is the highest possible value below 15000.

So instead of reversing the order of the statements, let's reverse the comparisons. While we're at it, check out in every possible scenario you are performing the same salary calculation and the same output. So those do not have to be repeated. The only thing different is the bonus calculation.

Let's put all that together and roll the bonus multiplier in there too... Look how simple (and readable) it becomes:

```
if (oldSalary < 15000.0)
    bonus = 0.05;
else if (oldSalary < 50000.0)
    bonus = 0.07;
else if (oldSalary < 100000.0)
    bonus = 0.10;
else
    bonus = 0.15;

bonus *= oldSalary;
total = oldSalary + bonus;

cout << "You will receive a raise of $" << bonus
     << ", for a new yearly salary of $" << total
     << endl;
```